# Exporting to PDF: scale changes print area

Tags: qgis, export

I have read similar questions, but I haven´t been able to do what I want in a quick way.

I want to export the area that I am seeing. For that, for example the scale is 1:8000, but I want the resolution of scale 1:2500.

In both options to export (Export map as PDF or with Composer) when I select the scale of 1:2500, the layout is reduced.

The only solution I have found is this: Export as PDF, copy the four coordinates in a notepad, change scale and, finally, copy the coordinates from notepad to QGIS. But I think there must be a more simple way.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Did you try "Set map extent to match main canvas extent" in print composer?

Comment: Yes, I extent the map after select the desire scale (1.2500 in the example) but the scale is changed automatically to the first value (1:8000 in my example).

Comment: The solution should be to extent the map, but the pixels should grow instead of being fixed (I suppose "wide" and "high" or something similar; my language is Spanish)

Comment: I guess you need another paper format. Make it bigger.

Comment: It seems you're confusing the terms "resolution" and "scale." They're not the same. You can change the export resolution in export settings in the layout panel, but resolution is measured in dpi (dots per inch), not as a ratio like 1:2500. If you want to export a map of a small area with the same resolution as a map with the scale 1:2500 has, make the map item bigger than your page.

Comment: You are right, csk; I´ll try to explain better: What I want is to print with the map layer corresponding to scale 1:2500 because this layer includes more information ("resolution") that layer corresponding to 1:8000. To view and select the complete area I have to use 1:8000 scale, but for printing I want to use information in 1:2500 scale.

Many thanks,

Comment: When I change the scale for exportint to pdf or with composer the area is reduced and the pdf does not include the complete area (the number of pixels is fixed; so the result is a more little area). I have a manual solution: I Initiate the exporting with 1:8000 scale; copy the four coordinates in a notepad; change the scale to 1:2500 (area is reduced consequently); copy the coordinates from notepad (the number of pixel is increased). In my opinion it is rare that what I can do manually is not able to do more automatically.

Many thanks,